# How to add Custom Image to Salesforce Communities?

Tags: community, force.com-sites, site.com, community-builder

I want to add a custom image to Salesforce Community

This is aleardy done in a test Sandbox the logo is accessible via {Community_url}/s/{imageName}

I am trying to add than in a new Sandbox

So the question is :

how to add an image in Salesforce to be able to access it, in a lightning component like this

```
<img src="{!'/s/logo.png'}"  alt="logo" />
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the salesforce site class

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm

```
Site.getPathPrefix()
```

This will give you the prefix of the current site

```
<img src="{!'/'+v.prefix+'/logo.png'}"  alt="logo" />
```

Comment: Thank you @Ratan, do you know where to upload those images ?

Comment: @benahm you can use static resource or documents

Comment: @benahm is this issue resolved?